# double & and move function in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I would like to use **parameter** in C++ to store back whatever value/object. 
In this example, I try to store the value from the global variable as a simplified example.

This code doesn't work,

```
int value = 20;

void returnPointer2(int* hello)
{
    hello = &value;
}

// It changes nothing 
int value2 = 100; 
returnPointer2(&value2);
cout << value2 << endl;
```

as I needed double pointer.

```
void returnPointer3(int** hello)
{
    *hello = &value;
}

int* vp2 = new int();
*vp2 = -30;  
returnPointer3(&vp2);
cout << *vp2 << endl; // expects 20
```

I reminded of the reference, and I can use pointer reference to get the same result.

```
void returnPointer4(int* & hello)
{
    cout << "value : " << value;
    hello = &value;
}

int* vp3 = new int();
*vp3 = -130;  
returnPointer4(vp3); // also expects 20, but much simpler to use
cout << "better : " << *vp3 << endl;
```

I tried with double &, and it compiles.

```
void returnPointer5(int&& hello)
{
    cout << "value : " << value;
    hello = value;
}
```

However, it doesn't compile with the input of integer variable.

```
int vp4 = 123; 
returnPointer5(vp4); // also expects 20, but even more simpler to use
cout << "best : " << vp4 << endl;
```

This is an error message.

```
pointer_return.cpp:31:6: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'void returnPointer5(int&&)'
void returnPointer5(int&& hello)
```

I happened to know about `move`, and it works with this code.

```
int vp4 = 123; 
returnPointer5(move(vp4)); // also expects 20, but much simpler to see
cout << "best : " << vp4 << endl;
```

What's the magic/logic behind this `move` function?

Comment: `void returnPointer4(int* & hello)` why using a pointer to a reference?

Comment: you are using everything totally wrong... use `*hello = value` in your first function

Comment: I think that he is trying to get the new variable to be pointed by the pointer of the public one.

Comment: `void returnPointer5(int* hello) { *hello = value; }` is that what you wanted? or `void returnPointer6(int** hello) { *hello = &value; }`?  The first puts the value of 'value' into 'hello' and the second puts the address of 'value' into 'hello'

Comment: but really you should just do `int returnValue()` or `int* returnAddress()` or `int& returnReference()`

Comment: "*I would like to use parameter in C++ to store back the value of global variable value.*" Why? Why not just take it *by value*? Why do you need a pointer here at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of stuff getting mixed in here, but to keep it simple I'll address your root question.

`&&` is nothing at all like `**`.

`&&` is an [rvalue reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx), while `**` is a pointer to a pointer.

---

As a second point, you are declaring in your function name what you want to do: `returnPointer4`.

You want to have a pointer to an integer returned back. `int*&` is the correct syntax for having a reference to a pointer.

---

Reading over your question again, why don't you use the following:

```
int& returnGlobalReference() {
    return value;
}
```

Then in your other function:

```
int& value2 = returnGlobalReference();
```

Answer (score 1):

The first attempt makes the classic mistake of passing a pointer by value, modifying its address in the function and expecting what it points to to change.

As mentioned in the comments,

```
void returnPointer2(int* hello)
{
    hello = &value; // don't do this, it only modifies what the 
                    // pointer hello, which resides in the stack, points to

    *hello = value; // do this instead. even though hello still resides in the                  
                    // stack, you're modifying the location that hello points to,
                    // which was your original intention

}
```

why do you want to pass pointers however? is the static variable not available when you call the function? (perhaps, different files?)

Comment: It's all in what is needed. If he needs a reference to the global variable, then he will need to use `hello = &value;` with hello declared as `int *&`.

Comment: yeah, agreed. i like your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The magic of std::move is:

> The actual declaration for std::move is somewhat more involved, but at its heart, it's just a static_cast to an rvalue reference.

Taken from [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

As Jeffery Thomas already said, a `&&` is not a reference to a reference, but a reference to a rvalue.